# How to enable flipview in windows store app to display multiple items simultaneously

Tags: flipview

I am dynamically generating images through C# , and when the page loads I want the user to be able to view more than one image at a time inside a flipview, but unfortunately when I am adding the images inside the flipview, only one image is visible at a time, and user has to scroll to watch another image. If I use gridview that solves my problem , but i don't want the gridview style scrollbar. Here is my code.

```
    HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(new    
                              Uri(@"http://indiamp3.com/music/index.php"));
    HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponseAsync().Result;
    StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream());
    string stream = sr.ReadToEnd();
    string reader = stream.Split(new string[] { "IndiaMp3.Com - Download & play free
                                 Indian hindi mp3 songs", "Random Albums" }, 
                                  StringSplitOptions.None)[1];
   List<string> readerLink = new List<string>();
  readerLink.AddRange(reader.Split(new string[] { "<img src='", ".jpg'" }, 
                                   StringSplitOptions.None));
   readerLink.RemoveAll(s => s.Contains("audio") == false);
   List<string> songList = new List<string>();
   List<string> imageLink = new List<string>();
   imageLink.AddRange(reader.Split(new string[] { "href='", "'>" }, 
                      StringSplitOptions.None));
   imageLink.RemoveAll(s => s.Contains("action=") == false);
   imageLink = imageLink.Distinct().ToList();
    List<Image> images = new List<Image>();
   foreach (string link in readerLink)
          {
                songList.Add(link.Split('/')[3]);
                // imageLink.Add("http://indiamp3.com/music/" + link + ".jpg");
                image = new Image();
                image.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(@"http://indiamp3.com/music/" + 
                                               link + ".jpg", UriKind.Absolute));
                image.Stretch = Stretch.None;
                image.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Left;
                image.VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Center;
                images.Add(image);
                fvLatest.Items.Add(image); // fvLatest is the name of the flipview 


            }
```

Answer (score 0):

I've searched for the same and the only answer I found is this:

> *I do not think FlipView is design for that, if you want to display multipe flip view, you could try to use other controls to render your content, and navigate by code.
>   best regards,
>   Sheldon _Xiao[MSFT]*

@ [MSDN](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsapps/en-US/80cf27da-7913-4c51-a264-bb6a399805dd/display-more-than-one-items-in-flipview?forum=winappswithcsharp)